# All fixtures blink then turn off

Tags: gfci

All fixtures (2 lights, 2 receptacles, 1 exhaust fan) blink, then turn off. Neither circuit breaker nor GFCI kick off. Wire = 12/2 w Ground.

Comment: All fixtures come off load on GFCI. Bidet plugged into GFCI receptacle.

Comment: Have you carefully checked the connections at the first stop past the GFCI?  Screws torqued properly?  Any  big loads plugged in recently? I would say check backstabs, but since it's #12 there better not be any backstabs in use!

Comment: Have you tried turning the lights off ? No load the system may continue to provide power, a night light is a good trouble shooting tool in this case as they draw almost no power, if the night light holds try the light, or the fan try to cut the problem in half but a bad connection on the hot or neutral at a back stab, wire nut or even a broken wire can cause this as Harper is referring to also. Back stabs 97% probability of the cause in my experience.

Comment: The wire for both the GFCI and following receptacle are wired with the newer side plates that are screwed down over the wire. Not technically "back stabs."  I've never seen a situation where the lights go out and receptacles go dead without either the breaker or GFCI tripping. They come back on after a short period of time.

Comment: By the way Harper and Ed thanks for your help.

Comment: GFCI and receptacle are brand new and are both second set installed. New 12/2 w/G has just been run from breaker to GFCI and 20 Amp breaker has been changed out. 2 lights and fan originally came off of old receptacle load side. I've added new GFCI and ran new receptacle and old fixtures off of new GFCI load side. All connections appear to be tight.